# I cannot get my map to display in leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have a HTML page that is using **`leaflet.js`** and for some reason I cannot get the map to display.

I have the API from **mapbox** in the correct place but no map. The following is the JS code,the markup and the CSS to see what I messed up on.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learn Maps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="night_class/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="night_class/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            //every part goes here
            var map = L.map('map').setView([45.46, -122.739], 4);
            L.tileLayer('https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/rodneyabutler.db94e2a6/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9kbmV5YWJ1dGxlciIsImEiOiJiYzd2SVVvIn0.R7uMtxUochQCrDmpiwg6QQ#4/45.51/-122.69', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
        }

    </script>


</head>


<body>

<div id="map">MAP</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

#map {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height:300px;
    width:50%;
    border: solid crimson 4px;
    /*background-color:#000;*/
}
```

Comment: what browser you're using ? open console and see if there is an error and update your question with errors in console

Comment: I think the URL you're using in the tileLayer might be wrong. You're giving the Share url you have got from the map. (Refer: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) `URL: http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` (it should be like this) Its better if you use Mapbox directly.

Comment: You may want to remove the mapbox token from the question text.

Answer (score 1):

with Leaflet, you need to have the div that holds the map set up before you create the map, or else the map object doesn't know where to go.  Try moving your script tags below the map div.

The final script should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Learn Maps</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

</head>


<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

<script>

        window.onload = function() {

        var tileLayer = L.tileLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png", {maxZoom: 18, attribution: 'MRLC, State of Oregon, State of Oregon DOT, State of Oregon GEO, Esri, DeLorme, HERE, TomTom, USGS, NGA, EPA, NPS, U.S. Forest Service'});

        var map = new L.map('map', {
            layers: tileLayer
        }).setView([45.46, -122.739], 4);

    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I am quite new to development and even newer to this forum. Thank you all for being supportive and assisting me. Kathy, your solution worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to use mapbox the same way as the ArcGIS server?

Comment: for your second question, MapBox is primarily intended to serve tilesets, though they can also host raster and geojson datasets.  The workflow for managing tilesets vs. data is explained briefly in [this blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/choosing-the-right-tool/).

Comment: Rodney - that's great!  I was a new developer when I started using Leaflet, and I found [this page](https://leanpub.com/leaflet-tips-and-tricks/read) very helpful.